# Google Apps Script - Editors Execute Script on Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I created a Google spreadsheet to help my team keep track of their calendar for the upcoming week.  The spreadsheet has 2 tabs:  an "Overview" tab and a "Details" tab. On the "Details" tab, the top row lists all of the weekdays through the end of the year and the left column lists the team members names.  For each day, the team member writes what school they will be at and the description of support.

The "Overview" tab has the same structure as the "Details" tab (i.e., dates across the top and names listed on the left), but provides a visual summary of where each person will be.  I wrote a script that takes the school name from the "Details" tab and enters it in the cell that corresponds to the correct person/date on the "Overview" tab.  Then it takes the description of support and creates a Note on the "Overview" tab with the description.  It also shades the cell on the Overview tab so I can see that support is planned.  So from the "Overview" tab, all I have to do is mouse over the cell and it will show me the planned support.

It works great in my own account.  However, I have shared the spreadsheet with some team members and it is not working.  I don't want my team to be able to edit the "Overview" tab because I only want them to input their information on the "Details" tab.  If I give them editing rights to the "Overview" tab, then they can change the Notes, cell colors, sheet structure, etc (that is why I want the Overview tab as view-only).  So, I protected the "Overview" tab so they cannot make edits.  However, because they cannot edit this sheet, it seems that the script will not run and update the Overview tab when they edit the Details tab.  I assume this is because they don't have permission (because the sheet is protected). When I remove the sheet protection, the script runs just fine for them.

Any thoughts on how I can get around this?  I really need to keep the Overview tab View-only.  Thanks.

Comment: How is your script triggered?

Comment: onEdit...but I created my own (onEdit1) instead of using the default onEdit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If, as you stated in comments, you use an **installable on Edit trigger** the problem you describe should **not occur** since *"When a script runs because of a trigger, the script runs using the identity of the person who installed the trigger, not the identity of the user whose action triggered the event. This is for security reasons. For example, if you install a trigger in your script, but your coworker performs the action that triggers the event, the script runs under your identity, not your coworker's identity. For complete information on this, see Understanding Permissions and Script Execution."*

see doc [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_triggers?hl=fr-FR)

---

**EDIT :** sorry, I didn't see the issue about this special case : [issue 1562 posted on july 2012, status "triaged"](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1562)

---

EDIT 2 : I tried @tracon6 suggestion to remove the protection temporarily but it doesn't work either... the script generates an error when trying to apply the protection.

### but

**as an EDIT 3**

I found a workaround that works !  We can add an editor just for the time we write to the targetSheet and remove it right after... using a `flush` in between it works.

here is the code I used to test :

```
function onEditInstallable(event) {
  var sheet = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  if(sheet.getName()=='Sheet1'){return};
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();
  var column = r.getColumn();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("TFA");
  var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var user = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getEditors()[1];
  var permission = targetSheet.getSheetProtection();
  permission.addUser(user);
  targetSheet.setSheetProtection(permission);
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  targetSheet.getRange(1,column).setValue('value change on sheet 2, column  : '+column);
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  permission.removeUser(user)
  targetSheet.setSheetProtection(permission)
}
```

---

### EDIT 4 :

Since it seems that many editors could have access to these sheets (see last comments), there has to be a way to know who is active on the spreadsheet. In a non domain environment this is not possible with a triggered function so I would suggest a small uiApp with a list from which the user has to choose, trigger that with an installable onOpen and store the value to use it in the main function.

Heres is a piece of code to handle that aspect.

```
function SpecialonOpen(){
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('Please select your email in this list').setWidth(300).setHeight(300);
  var list = app.createListBox().setName('list')
  var editors = s.getEditors();
  for(var n in editors){
    list.addItem(editors[n].getEmail());
  }
  var handler = app.createServerHandler('getMail').addCallbackElement(list);
  var btn = app.createButton('select',handler);
  s.show(app.add(list).add(btn))
}

function getMail(e){
  var email = e.parameter.list;
  var editors = ScriptProperties.getProperty('currentEditors')||' ';
  if(editors.indexOf(email)==-1){
    editors+=(','+email);
  ScriptProperties.setProperty('currentEditors',editors);
  }
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication().close();
  var editors = ScriptProperties.getProperty('currentEditors').split(',');
  if(editors[0].length<2){editors.splice(0,1)};
  Logger.log(editors)
  return app
}
```

[image]

You should also add a function to reset this list at some moment... don't know what would be best ? on a daily base maybe ? I'll let this to you ;-)

Comment: Yes, thanks for sharing...I came across that info, too.  So that is why I thought it would work. Part of the script changes the cell color when the text is entered on the Details tab.  This works as it should all the time.  However, as soon as I protect the Overview tab, the script doesn't push the text from the Details to the Overview tab. Perhaps the "sheet protection" trumps the user (even though the script is being run as the owner [me]). Still perplexed...

Comment: Do you know if I need to "Deploy as Web App"?  I currently do not have any "doGet" code in my script.  Thanks.

Comment: Nope, you don't, deployment is only for standalone apps. If I find some time I'll try to reproduce your situation to help further.

Comment: Great thanks.  I can make share the file with you if that would help.

Comment: Yes,that would be easier... my email is sergegabet and is a gmail account.

Comment: I just shared two files (from my "etomiami" account).  I changed to "Overview" tab name to "TFA" and the "Details" tab name to "TFA Log".  One file has the TFA/Overview tab without protection.  The other file (that has _PROTECTED in the filename has sheet protection on the first tab and does not allow edits to be made when you input info on the log tab.

Comment: These are copies of the file, so you can mess around on the file without the sheet protection to get an idea of the functionality.

Comment: I tried doing Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(), but that returns null (I assume this is to protect the identity of the user.  Is there any way to get their email address?  I don't think adding/removing protection for all editors every time an edit is made is feasible...many spreadsheets might have 15+ editors...

Comment: I tried too and indeed the triggered function can't get the user email but ... (always a but) you could get it in another function, write it to scriptProperties and pick it up there ? didn't try this but it should be possible. Are you (and the editors) in a domain ? a google apps account ?

Comment: To answer your question, no we are not in a domain.  I like the latest version...quick question: what is the trigger for getMail(e)?  It says that I do not have permission to run the script when I open the file as an editor.

Answer (score 1):

Do the Overview tab and the Details tab need to be in the same spreadsheet?

Perhaps you can have the Overview tab in a spreadsheet that only you can access and have the Details tab in a spreadsheet that everyone else can access -- then you can modify your script to use the information in the new "Details Spreadsheet" to update the new "Overview Spreadsheet".

Alternatively, in your script, you could turn off the protection on the Overview tab, then run the main part of the script, then turn on the protection on the Overview tab again before the script ends (see https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/page-protection#setProtected(Boolean))

Admittedly, neither of these options are as clean the onEdit option.

Comment: Hmm, I hadn't thought of having the script turn off the protection, then push the data, then turn the sheet protection back on. I will try that tomorrow.  I wonder if the user will be allowed to change the sheet protection (even though the script should run as the owner [me]).  Also, any idea as to how this would work if multiple people are editing the Details tab at the same time (which is going to happen a lot)?

Comment: Do you know if I need to "Deploy as Web App"?  I currently do not have any "doGet" code in my script.  Thanks.

Comment: You can set the protection of each sheet in the spreadsheet separately. Right click on the Overview sheet tab at the bottom of the screen then choose "Protect Sheet" then choose "Only Me".  This allows you have have multiple people continue to work on the Details tab and not have the ability to modify the Overview tab.  In case you need it, here is additional information regard PageProtection functions: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/page-protection

Comment: I see your question about "Deploy as Web App".  Could you provide more background?  Why do you think you would need to (or want to) "Deploy as Web App"?

Comment: I am not familiar with deploying as web apps, but I didn't know if this would help me circumvent the issue of an editor being able to run the onEdit script and have it edit a protected tab (that they don't have access to edit).  It seems like when you deploy as web app you have the option to have the script execute as the owner (which is what I want).  However, it seems from Google's text that all installable triggers SHOULD execute as the owner (me).  If that is the case, it seems that "Sheet Protection" trumps that!

Comment: Got it. Thanks for providing the background. Serge clearly knows more about this issue than I do, so I'll defer to him on this.

Comment: @tracon6 your idea was a good one, don't know why I cannot make it work... anyway it put me on the right track to find the working solution, thx &+1

Answer (score 0):

Here is a hacky workarround you can try: publish the script as a content service with anonymous access, and call it with urlFetch from your trigger, passing the necessary param to your service.
This should cause the code to execute in a different context where the effective user is the script publisher and not te user. Will be slower thou.

Comment: Zig, how do I go about doing this (I am new to GAS)?  Do I basically just put all of the code in a doGet() function and deploy it as a web app?  Then I use urlFetch to call that address?

Comment: More specifically, I assume that my parameter would be the "event" right?

Comment: Basically yes, the code that used to be on onEdit. Then in doGet(e) e will have the params you passed as in urlFetch("yourserviceurl?x=5")  will get e.parameter.x=5 in doGet(e). Your params are whatever you need to complete the writes in the right places.

Comment: I must add that last time I tried that was like 2 years ago and I found out apps script doesnt love to be cslled recursively like that. I tried 5 levels of recursion and it almost never got to the 5th. But will only one urlFetch level you should be ok.

Comment: function onEdit1(event) {

  UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbx3_g2-mah2hGAjfM17768LbvXjXRrqiaCRId2c9V6t_UqF_LQ/exec", event);

Comment: I pressed enter too soon, but basically this is what is triggered onEdit from my spreadsheet.  Then the web app is:  function doGet(event) { all of my code }...is this correct?  I think I might be passing the parameter wrong...

Comment: you have to pass the param as string, and as part of the url itself when passing it to urlFetch with the "?" per my example above. to convert the event to string, convert it to json.

Comment: Hey Zig, I am still stuck on this.  What should the doGet(e) return?  Also, does the script execute from the web app? Or does the web app return code and the script executes on the spreadsheet?  Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps if you have come across a piece of code that already does this you could link it here so I could check it out.  Thanks.

Comment: @Zig, after a few tests we made with Chris it appears that it is not possible to write to a protected sheet in a shared spreadsheet from a call to a contentService Webapp.But it works well with an unshared spreadsheet, so this solution is a good one after all, not too slow btw :-)  thanks for suggesting.

Comment: From your content script you should be able to write to the sprewdsheet provided the ss is shared write and the protected ranges and sheets are also shared write with the script owner. The easiest way to achieve that is to be the spreadsheets owner (ss and scripts having the same owner, sort of a system user you reserve for the app)

Comment: Serge! My mortal enemy from http://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/topusers. :)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you protect the Overview sheet using the options in the Data tab and set permissions for edit to 'Only you'. This will protect the sheet from everyone, even editors, leaving the sheet in View Only mode for everyone except yourself.